# Configuration Management of a set of windows App servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, puppet, configuration

We have several sets of app servers in a clients network running different code. Each set has Dev, UAT and Prod and we are developing outside the network.

At the moment I'm manually pushing the various code updates from my dev box (the default master I guess) via citrix to a shared directory on the dev server of each set, based on date changed, and from there to each of the other servers in turn as the code cycle progresses.

This was OK for one set, but is now becoming painful and error prone.

I'm wondering what people think is a viable alternative. We have limited or no outside access from the app servers (so something like Chef hosted would be difficult), and there are no nix boxes of any description in the network that I could use as a master unfortunately for either Chef or Puppet.

What are others using? Any suggestions?

Peter.

Comment: You say you where pushing it on via Citrix, which means you have a virtual environment, is it really too hard to spawn a small nix box? Not trying to be facetious.

Comment: I SO wish I could do that (infact that we could do the entire app on an OS stack, but sadly no. The infrastructure team have never seen a penguin in their life.